# Trying to display xml results in Html using js

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom

im trying to display xml information which comes from this file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <key name="The Mintoons #690" type="int">1</key>
    <key name="The Mintoons #368" type="int">2</key>
    <key name="The Mintoons #979" type="int">3</key>
    <key name="The Mintoons #185" type="int">4</key>
    <key name="The Mintoons #499" type="int">5</key>
    <key name="The Mintoons #554" type="int">6</key>
</root>
```

and my html is coded like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table,th,td {
  border : 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td {
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Reveal Results</button>
<br><br>
<table id="demo"></table>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "result.xml", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("key");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i] +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getAttribute("name")[0] +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

i wanted to display in a table

| NFT | Rarity |
| --- | --- |
| The Mintoons #690 | 1 |
| The Mintoons #368 | 2 |

like this but rather than like this it displays

| NFT | Rarity |
| --- | --- |
| [Object Element] | T |
| [Object Element] | T |

i dunno what i did wrong here

Comment: `x[i]` is an object (the `<key>` tag), you probably want `x[i].getAttribute("name")`. And `x[i].getAttribute("name")[0]` gives the first letter of the name attribute, you probably want `x[i].textContent` .

Comment: As a side note, building HTML content from external sources is a security weakness point. If the XML file is from a fully trusted source then it's okay but better build elements and add content to their `.textContent`

Comment: i changed the code according to your first comment and it worked thanks, i know that using external sources creates security issues but it is for university project so its not that important. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

(Forming it as an answer after clarification in the comments)

Since `x` is a collection of DOM elements (in this case XML nodes but it could be HTML elements as well), `x[i]` is a single element object, so outputting it results in the string '[Object Element]'.

`x[i].getAttribute("name")` returns the content of the elements `name` attribute, which is the string "The Mintoons #690" for the first `x[0]`. So this could be used for the first column of the table.

`x[i].getAttribute("name")[0]` simply returns the first character of said string, which is "T" - probably not the desired result here. Retriving the inner content of the element (the content between the opening tag and closing tag - "1" for the first element) can be done with `x[i].textContent`.

So as a conclusion, `function myFunction()` can be:

```
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("key");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getAttribute("name") +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].textContent +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
```

As a side note, building an HTML sequence from an input or a fetched source can create a security weakness point. It may be fine if the source is absoultely trusted, but a more secure equivalent would be

```
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("key");

  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr, th, td;

  tr = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.textContent = "Artist";
  tr.appendChild(th);
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.textContent = "Title";
  tr.appendChild(th);
  table.appendChild(tr);

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
    tr = document.createElement("tr");
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.textContent = x[i].getAttribute("name");
    tr.appendChild(td);
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.textContent = x[i].textContent;
    tr.appendChild(td);
    table.appendChild(tr);
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(table);
}
```